# Inserting a line with special characters (',`,$ etc) into a file using BASH

Tags: bash, sed

Hello I need help with some bash script.

I need to insert the below line into a file at a specific line number

```
su - test -c '$HOME/scripts/auto start' >> /home/test/auto_start.`date +%h_%d_%y`.log 2>&1
```

In the bigger problem statement, the **line** to be inserted at a specified **line number** & into the **file**, all are dynamic & need to be fetched from a csv file.

The csv file looks like:

```
$ cat test_file.csv
TARGET_NODE,TARGET_FILE,TARGET_LINE,NEW_LINE
10.10.10.10,test_file.csv,2,su - test -c '$HOME/scripts/auto start' >> /home/test/auto_start.`date +%h_%d_%y`.log 2>&1
```

Have tried using sed in many ways, but failed. We can't use python due to system limitations.

The simple way to test it:

```
seq 4|sed 's/<LINE_NUMBER>/<NEW_TEXT>/'
```

So we tried using:

```
seq 4|sed 's/2/'su - test -c '$HOME/scripts/auto start' >> /home/test/auto_start.`date +%h_%d_%y`.log 2>&1'/'
```

Comment: The 'test_file.csv' implies that it should be updating itself (it refers to itself in line 2). If you do that, the column structure will be broken (the test_file.csv has TARGET_NODE column). Can you clarify what you are trying to do ?

Comment: the test_file.csv on the target node 10.10.10.10 is different that the local file. Even though the file names are same, but they reside on different node.

Comment: You will have to clarify (in the question) how will the remote files be access. Otherwise, the local sed will only be able to access the local test_file.csv

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say if you wanted the new line printed before or after or instead of the existing line so here's all 3:

```
$ seq 4 | awk -F, 'NR==FNR{line[$3]=$4; next} FNR in line{print line[FNR]} 1' test_file.csv -
1
su - test -c '$HOME/scripts/auto start' >> /home/test/auto_start.`date +%h_%d_%y`.log 2>&1
2
3
4
```

.

```
$ seq 4 | awk -F, 'NR==FNR{line[$3]=$4; next} 1; FNR in line{print line[FNR]}' test_file.csv -
1
2
su - test -c '$HOME/scripts/auto start' >> /home/test/auto_start.`date +%h_%d_%y`.log 2>&1
3
4
```

.

```
$ seq 4 | awk -F, 'NR==FNR{line[$3]=$4; next} FNR in line{$0=line[FNR]} 1' test_file.csv -
1
su - test -c '$HOME/scripts/auto start' >> /home/test/auto_start.`date +%h_%d_%y`.log 2>&1
3
4
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell and for any string from that CSV on every UNIX box

Answer (score 0):

If you have no system limitations for using perl :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
seq 4 | perl -pe '
BEGIN {
    open CSV, shift; # Open test_file.csv
    <CSV>; # Ignore first line
    # Get line number and command
    ($n, $c) = <CSV> =~ /^(?:[^,]+,){2}([^,]+),(.*)/;
    }
{ s/.*/$c/ if ($. == $n); } # Replace line with number $n
' test_file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Just properly quote the line and use different `s` command separator because `/` is used in replacement string... escape special regex characters in replacement string, like `&` or `\`.

```
$ seq 4 | sed 's~2~su - test -c '\''$HOME/scripts/auto start'\'' >> /home/test/auto_start.`date +%h_%d_%y`.log 2>\&1~'
1
su - test -c '$HOME/scripts/auto start' >> /home/test/auto_start.`date +%h_%d_%y`.log 2>&1
3
4
```

with `awk`:

```
seq 4 | awk -vvar='su - test -c '\''$HOME/scripts/auto start'\'' >> /home/test/auto_start.`date +%h_%d_%y`.log 2>&1' 'NR==2{$0=var}1'
```

I discourage the usage of backticks `. Do not use them. Use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: If you put a space between `-v` and `var=` then the script will be portable to all POSIX (and other) awks rather than gawk-specific.